# $T$ is an isometry if and only if $\langle Tx, Ty \rangle = \langle x, y \rangle$

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, hilbert-spaces, inner-products, isometry

I want to prove:

> A linear mapping $T:X \to Y$ between two pre-Hilbert spaces is an
>   isometry  if and only if  the inner products $\langle Tx, Ty \rangle = \langle x, y \rangle$ for all $x, y \in X$.

=>

$4 \langle Tx,Ty \rangle = \|Tx+Ty\|^2-\|Tx-Ty\|^2 = \|T(x+y)\|^2-\|T(x-y)\|^2  = \|x+y\|^2-\|x-y\|^2 = 4 \langle x,y \rangle $ 
Therefore $\langle Tx, Ty \rangle = \langle x, y \rangle$

<=

How to show that?

Comment: Extra credit: show you don't need to assume $T$ is linear.

Comment: What definition of isometry do you use? The other direction should be straight-forward.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that\begin{align}\bigl\lVert Tx\bigr\rVert^2&=\bigl\langle Tx,Tx\bigr\rangle\\&=\langle x,x\rangle\\&=\lVert x\rVert^2.\end{align}

Comment: Thank you very much! Can we also simplify my proof of converse direction?

Comment: @AnalysisNewbie No, I cannot, because what you did is what I would have done.

Answer (score 1):

Simply
$$
\|Tx\| = \sqrt{\langle Tx, Tx\rangle} = \sqrt{\langle x, x \rangle} = \|x\|.
$$

Comment: Thank you very much! Can we also simplify my proof of converse direction?